# Django: color test result in console

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a Django project for which I have tests (nothing special).

The thing is I'd like to have colored results when running tests and I don't know how to do that.

On a daily basis, I run tests from my Ubuntu terminal with the command

`python3 ./backend/manage.py test --settings="backend.settings.testing" backend/ --no-input --verbosity=2`

and applying the migrations looks like this at the beginning of the tests :

[image]

whereas the tests themselves have uncolored results like so :

[image]

My question is :

Is there a simple way to get those `ok` colored in green and if applicable `ko` in red ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's simple enough but Pycharm can do that.[image]

Comment: I'm personally using VSCode. But in the case my tests run in i.e. CircleCI, the fact that it works in PyCharm won't help :P ^^